# GameObject walk onto platform Unity2D

Tags: unity

I currently am working on a 2D game designed for android and iOS. I have a repeatedly spawning enemy game object which comes in from the left. I want the enemy game object to walk onto a slope which leads to a platform. I've tried adding physics rendering but it doesn't seem to work. I tried adding colliders to both and still nothing. The enemy object just goes straight through the slope and doesn't actually climb it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Physics2D Rigidbody collider

Comment: Can you post code that you use to move your enemies? Are you moving it by applying forces to the RigidBody?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add both Colliders and Rigidbodies to both the enemy object and to the platform.

**Platform:** Set it to kinematic (and no-gravity just cuz, and lock the position/rotation) and set its position to where you want it.

**Enemy:** Set it non-kinematic and to use gravity, and add a velocity to it to make it move up the slope.

For fun you can add materials to the ground and the player to control their friction (is your platform icy/slippery? etc.).

Comment: @FShiwani on stackexchange.com, if you find an answer useful, you should up-vote it, and if it answers your question, you should click the checkmark to accept it. Thanks, and welcome to Stack Exchange